# TextView inside LinearLayout stretches the LinearLayout and fill_parent fix causes weight flip

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-layout-weight

If I have 2 LinearLayouts split %50/%50 everything is fine. Weights are 1 and 1. As soon as I add a TextView inside the top LinearLayout, it stretches that layout. I use `wrap_content` as the documentation says I should when it comes to weights.

As you can see the red and green should be split evenly and text on grey background should be inside red box. Here is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#ff0000"
>
 <TextView
 android:text="@string/hello"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#cccccc"
 android:textColor="#000000"/>      
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#00ff00"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now if I switch to "fill parent" as follows it actually works but it creates another problem. Here is the code (so far so good):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >
     <TextView
     android:text="@string/hello"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#cccccc"
     android:textColor="#000000"/>      
    </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    >
    </LinearLayout>
```

So looking at above we were forced to use `fill_parent` and we would think like we fixed the problem but here is the problem if we are using `fill_parent` (I took out the TextView just to show the problem, TextView doesn't make the problem go away anyways):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >
    </LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    >
    </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I assign the weights 3 (top red) and 2 (bottom green) but what actually happens is they get flipped: The red becomes 2 and bottom becomes 3. Just measure the pixels too see.

Here are the results of the 3 codes:

[image]

Just to be clear, every single time the layout was wrapped inside this (the top layout):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

With XML `version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"` and proper namespace.

Comment: Actually, what's the problem? Your code seems to work as it is supposed to.

Comment: TextView is inside LinearLayout so why does it stretch the LinearLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Combined child view weights should add up to 1..... Eg. .3, .3, .4 = 1, or 100%

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a child view to the bottom layout.